# To check for error in a MySQL transaction

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to carry out a transaction in MySQL. If any error is present, I wish to rollback or else i want to commit. Is there any code to carryout these operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Declare/Handler syntax to keep trace of the exceptions, then commit or rollback depending on the value. Here an example :

```
DELIMITER //
BEGIN
  DECLARE `fail` bool default 0;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `fail` = 1;
  START TRANSACTION;
  INSERT .. 
  UPDATE ..
  W/E...
  IF `fail` THEN
    ROLLBACK;
  ELSE
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
END//
DELIMITER;
```

See documentation for more info on the [DECLARE..HANDLER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-handler.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for a similar solution. I will definitely try it.

Comment: @Sasu You'e welcome :). Feel free to comment if you encounter problems implementing it.

Comment: If you dont mind, can u please try to provide on answer for this question? It would be a great help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672221/to-call-mysql-stored-procedure-from-c-sharp-using-linq

Comment: Please mention if this syntax is usable without Stored Procedure like from within SQL Statements in Middle-ter (like, SQL-Statements from within PHP Script) ?